# Cannot convert return expression of type 'CustomProfileCell' to return type 'UITableViewCell'

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uitableview

Thi is my code

```
//
//  FirstViewController.swift
//  tabbed
//
//  Created by on 7/18/18.
//  Copyright © 2018 LR Web Design. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class FirstViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var profileTableView: UITableView!

    var profileArray = [Profile]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        profileTableView.delegate = self

        profileTableView.dataSource = self

        profileTableView.register(UINib(nibName: "ProfileCell",bundle: nil) , forCellReuseIdentifier: "customProfileCell")

        retrieveProfiles()

    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customProfileCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomProfileCell 
        cell.profileImage.image = UIImage(named: profileArray[indexPath.row].profileImage)
        cell.profileName.text = profileArray[indexPath.row].name
        cell.deviceCount.text = profileArray[indexPath.row].deviceCount 
        return cell
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return profileArray.count
    } 
    func retrieveProfiles() {

        let p1 = Profile()
        p1.name = "John"
        p1.deviceCount = "10"
        p1.profileImage = "john"
        profileArray.append(p1)

        let p2 = Profile()
        p2.name = "Jane"
        p2.deviceCount = "5"
        p2.profileImage = "jane"
        profileArray.append(p2)

        let p3 = Profile()
        p3.name = "Andrew"
        p3.deviceCount = "4"
        p3.profileImage = "andrew"
        profileArray.append(p3)

        self.profileTableView.reloadData()

    }

}
```

I kept getting

> Cannot convert return expression of type 'CustomProfileCell' to return type 'UITableViewCell'

[image]

Comment: class name is **CustomProfileCell** ??

Comment: Class name on what line ?

Comment: I mean do you have **class CustomProfileCell :UITableViewCell** ???

Comment: I don't. How do I added ? Which line should I added ?

Comment: declare below import UIKit and above class FirstViewController -->

class CustomProfileCell : UITableViewCell {
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you should return a custom class of Type `UITableViewCell` , the return will compile only if

```
class CustomProfileCell : UITableViewCell {
   // here outlets hooked to xib
}
```

Comment: I think you are right. I will accept when I can. :) Thanks for you help. I understand more now.

Answer (score 0):

ok my problem is solved by this way

I used the UICollectionView in storyboard but In the class I used the protocols of UITableView
so when I changed it my issue is solved